# Trying to use If statement to mark a cell with "X" if users exist in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which tracks users and the groups they belong to. Normally, I need to go user by user, group by group to find the match and place an "X" in that cell. It's long and tedious, so I'm hoping someone may have a better solution.

Here's what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

I can get a list of all users in each group (SharePoint) but I need to track this information in Excel. I'm thinking something like this would be start: =if((A2="user1","user2","user5","userN"),"X","")

I'm not sure if this formula would work but that's kind of the logic I have behind it. I'd like to find a way where I can easily and quickly switch the names because it's a long list.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SharePoint. Do you have the User-Group relationship in a table in excel? If yes, I could suggest one way.

Comment: Sorry the list I get in SharePoint is just a normal list of users in that group. From there I usually go into excel and put an X by the name for the users under the group they belong to. I'm trying to automate this a little by taking the names from sharepoint and putting them in a formula, copy down the list of names under the group and if the name on the list matches the name in excel place an X in that cell to indicate that this user is in the group. I don't really have relationships set up other than the image above.

Comment: Hmm, by relationships, I meant you have a user, and the group it belongs to next to it. I'm still not sure how your data is organised, but could you perhaps copy all the users in a group into a single column in excel in another sheet? And repeat for each group, making sure that each group is in another column? Or do you have the users in a list as in what you mentioned, i.e. `"user1","user2","user5","userN"`?

Comment: No the only thing I have in excel is from the picture above. All users on the Y-Axis and Groups on the X-Axis. I have the users in a list but not formated like that, just: Mike Stuart, Casey Jones, Jessica Milne, etc etc. I can clean up the list of names in excel pretty easily though.

Comment: when you dump the data to excel from sharepoint, what will the sheet look like?  (honestly this just seems like it would be a pivot table.)

Comment: I can't get the data from SharePoint to Excel other by copy and pasting the names within each group. I literally have to click group by group and special paste the names in excel, then trim and mid them to remove additional characters. It's a really stupid process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I hope I understood your issues.

Copy and paste the users in a separate sheet in the workbook (say `Sheet2`), so that for Group1, you have a single cell, example:

```
                 A
Mike Stuart, Casey Jones, Jessica Milne
```

On the data tab, you can use `Text to Column` > `Delimited` > `Comma` to get this:

```
     A             B              C
Mike Stuart | Casey Jones | Jessica Milne
```

Meaning, you have one user in one column. Preferably, all the group 1 users should be in this row.

In your sheet with users and groups, you then use the formula in cell B2 and drag it down:

```
=IF(ISNA(HLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$1:$1, 1, 0)), "", "X")
```

You can put the other groups below the first group, so that row 2 of `Sheet2` has all the users in group2, row 3 in `Sheet2` has all the users in group 3, etc.

For group 2, you'll use:

```
=IF(ISNA(HLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$2:$2, 1, 0)), "", "X")
                             ^  ^
```

The `^` show what I have changed.

`HLOOKUP` works as follows:

`HLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, row_index, [range_lookup])`

`lookup_value` is the value you're looking for, here each user in your final sheet.

`table_array` is the table in which the formula looks for. Here, it's `$1:$1`, so that the formula looks for the `lookup_value` in Row 1 of `Sheet2`.

`row_index` is 1 because we're looking in one row only. You can make some research as to how to use it if you want.

`[range_lookup]` is optional, but defaults to approximate match, which is not what you generally want. Put `0` there to mean "exact match".

Comment: OMG that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much, this makes my job so much easier. Wow, thank you!

Comment: @Batman Welcome! That's why I wanted to get a clear picture of what you had before posting an answer ^^

Comment: Do you know why a name might be getting skipped even is it's spelt correctly?

Comment: @Batmen: Hmm... could there have been spaces before or after the names? Spaces would cause non-matching names =/ You can try to use `=trim()` on all the names in your table and those in the reference sheet, copy and paste as values to remove the formulas and then replace the old data with the one you just created. Otherwise, I'm not sure =/ But if it works, great!

Comment: Hey Jerry, I was wondering if you might know what the best way would be to take the table I have above and generate a list. Basically an output like this: Group1 - user 3, group2, group 3 - user 2 and 5, etc. The format isn't important. Right now I'm going group by group filtering, copying and pasting the users, clearing the filter, repeat. Pretty slow.

Comment: @Batman I didn't know you had to filter each time, that sure sounds tedious :( If you don't use the filter, what happens? Is there a way to export the SharePoint data as an xml file? That might make it a bit faster. Also, I just realised that you can also avoid the trim by replacing all ", " (comma space) by a special character, say `:` and then split by `:` in the text to column wizard.

Comment: Well what i'm going with the filtering is for another task. Before I was trying to place an X on the right users. Your solution worked perfectly. Now I'm trying to get a list of users in each group (basically those who have an X). It's kinda of another question but since it's using the same information I thought I'd ask you.

Comment: @Batman Oh, but don't you have the `Sheet2` containing those? I mean, don't you have all users who are in group 1 in row 1, all users who are in group 2 in row 2, etc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32037/discussion-between-batman-and-jerry)

Comment: @Batman For some reason, I'm no more able to connect to the chat :( It's getting really late where I am, I guess we can continue tomorrow. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hey no worries, thanks for taking the time to go through it with me

Answer (score 2):

Using pivot tables he's an example of what could be done.
[image: enter code here]

Comment: Yea that would be great. My problem is that my data doesn't come like this. Some sites have 90+ groups, it would take a long time to organize the data. I like how it gives a total at the end so you know how many users are in a group and vice versa. I should learn how to use Pivot Tables soon.